# Reducing the number of rows in a matrix without loosing the rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $m \times n$, $m > n$ matrix with rank $n$. I want to compute a full rank $n \times n$ matrix $B$ by row operations over matrix $A$. In other words, I want to find an $n \times m$ matrix $T$, s.t., $B = TA$ is full rank for any $A$. How can I find such a matrix $T$?

Comment: Do you mean you want the same $T$ to work for every $A$?

Comment: You can do elementary row operations on $A$ to bring it to reduced row-echelon form, and then delete the $m-n$ all-zero rows at the bottom.

Comment: @David: Yes, if possible.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Your are right, but my question is a special case of a more general problem. The general problem is so that your solution cannot be used for that.

Comment: If you don't ask the question you actually want to know about, how do you expect to get a useful answer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I think my question, as I asked it above, is clear. I am looking for a matrix $T$ as described in the question that works for any $A$.

Comment: I think it's pretty easy to see that no such $T$ exists. Given any $n\times m$ matrix $T$, there's an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ of rank $n$ such that the rank of $TA$ is less than $n$. Just let one column of $A$ be in the nullspace of $T$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thank you, I think your comment is an acceptable answer.

Comment: Good. You can write it up and post it as an answer.